# Apriori Alg in R

Tags: r, apriori

I am using this code

```
df_itemList<- read.csv('data.3.txt')

write.csv(df_itemList,"ItemList.csv", row.names = TRUE)

txn = read.transactions(file="ItemList.csv", rm.duplicates= TRUE, format="basket",sep=",",cols=1)

 basket_rules <- apriori(txn,parameter = list(sup = 0.01, conf = 0.5,target="rules"))
```

To run Apriori Alg on this Data [image]

Look like this after converting it to df_itemList.CSV

[image]

the code works well and generates about 29000 rules for data sets consisting of 99 records (rows)

But my data has (10000 records)

for any data set has 101 records or more, the code executes in milliseconds, and gives just 4 meaningless rules .....

and I get this response in console

[image]

My questions is: How can I run the Apriori Alg on a bigger Dataset, more than 99 records.
Or why doesn't my code work for bigger Dataset???

Comment: 1) you haven't actually asked a question 2) I don't really understand what you're saying. It's not clear to me what some things represent because you tried to be very brief - almost like we were talking face to face but unlike that situation I can't just stop you to clarify what you're referring to. I would recommend rewriting your question to actually include a question and to make anything you refer to very clear about what you're talking about.

Comment: sorry, I thought the photos could explain....
I meant I am using Apriori Alg on my data shown in photo.
I expect from Apriori to investigate for rules in my data, and it did so for dataset consists of 99 records or less.
When I execute the algorithm for bigger dataset, I get the respond as in the last photo. @Dason

Comment: And in  the basket_rules I found just 4 trivial rules
   lhs    rhs support   confidence lift   count
[1] {}  => {1} 0.9995002 0.9995002  1.0000 2000 
[2] {}  => {0} 0.9995002 0.9995002  1.0000 2000 
[3] {1} => {0} 0.9995002 1.0000000  1.0005 2000 
[4] {0} => {1} 0.9995002 1.0000000  1.0005 2000 
it seems very strange for me that the program stop working when the data is bigger. It doesn't even try to, because I get response in very short time.
@Dason

Comment: Did you read the help with the `?apriori`? Because it is explained in the **Notes on run time and memory usage**.